# Laravel Eloquent query not running on Production at AWS instance

Tags: php, laravel-5, lumen

I am using Lumen

```
$employee = Employee::where('emp_pin', $request->input('emp_pin'))->first();

    $tempEmpTiming = 
    EmployeeTimings::where('employee_id',$employee['id'])
        ->where('status',Constant::CHECKED_IN)
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```

running this query, working fine on my local machine but it is not working on AWS instance. what could be the reason. The Only difference is at my local php5.6 is up and on AWS php7 is running. i have downgraded the php version doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide the error log?

Comment: lumen.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'App\Enum\Constant' not found in /var/www/cleaner/app/Http/Controllers/EmployeeController.php:71
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController->employeeCheckIn(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 /var/www/cleaner/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/cleaner/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()

Comment: It looks like maybe you haven't uploaded all of your files? I don't recognise `App\Enum\Constant`.

Comment: Tried running `composer dump` at the project root?